# normalization of probability density on a surface

Tags: probability-distributions

Let $p(x)$ ($x\in \mathbb{R}^d$) be a probability density function defined on $\mathbb{R}^d$. Assume we have a closed surface $S\subset \mathbb{R}^d$, on which points follow this function $g(x) = 0$. If I want to distinguish points on this surface by their probability density, I guess it is to look for a probability density function defined on the closed surface $S$.

Here is my try: intuitively, it seems that the density defined on the surface, which I denote it by $p_s(x)$, should follow

$\int_{C} p_s(x) d\sigma_s(x) = Z^{-1} \int_{x\in \mathbb{R}^d} p(x) \delta(g(x))\delta(C(x))dx$  for any well-defined section $C \subset S$,

where $Z = \int_{x\in \mathbb{R}^d} p(x) \delta(g(x))dx$.

I don't know whether it is correct or not. It looks strange and I haven't been able to find any related reference to explain that. It is well-known how to, for instance, find marginal probability density in $R^d$, but what if I don't want to normalize the density according to the axis, e.g. find marginal probability density to x-axis $f_x(x)$ or to y-axis $f_y(y)$? what if I want to do it on a surface? You can assume the surface is smooth.

I am not sure whether my analysis makes sense. It is possible I made a wrong analogy as well. Any hint would help me.

Comment: As your probability has a density wrt Lebesgue measure, your closed hypersurface $S$ is locally of probability zero, so that it is of probability zero, whatever may the codimension of $S$ be. Look at a case of an hyperplane for instance...

Comment: But is there any way to distinguish points on the surface in this case? It is true that the hyperplane has zero probability but is it possible to have some density? Like the probability for any point in exponential distribution is zero but it still has some density.